# conﬁdence intervals are not well justiﬁed after the use of cross-validation?

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-validation

I am reading the book "Deep Learning" by Goodfellow, Bengio, & Courville (2016).

They state:
"Though these conﬁdence intervals are not well justiﬁed after the use of cross-validation, it is still common practice to use them to declare that algorithm A is better than algorithm B only if the conﬁdence interval of the error of algorithm A lies below and does not intersect the conﬁdence interval of algorithm B. (P. 121)"

Can anyone explain why the conﬁdence intervals are not well justiﬁed after the use of cross-validation?

Comment: Please tell us what *these* confidence intervals are. Without that, no justification or explanation is possible.